# wordpress 3.1.2 | plugin SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam issue on Lost Your Password Page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

We have installed Plugin SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam. Things works fine. But while testing we face on issue. If we enable SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam on Lost Your Password Page, then if User Clicks "Get New Password" button without any value in any textfield, page gets redirected to Blog Home Page with a message at bottom as :- 
**comment submission error
Your comment submission failed for the following reasons: You did not enter a CAPTCHA phrase. Press your browser's back button and try again..
Return to the original entry.**

Ideally it should show the error message on the same page as it shows in case of login page.

Thanks,
Niranjan

Comment: can some one please help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using SweetCaptcha???
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sweetcaptcha-revolutionary-free-captcha-service/
from

http://www.SweetCaptcha.com/
just saying...

Josh.

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html